# Restore MP3 file from binary data

Tags: c++, audio, binary, mp3, encode

My taks is to restore an mp3 file, wich is coded bit-per-bit in a PNG file. I got the right bits from the PNG RGB data (per pixel) in a vector. I'm using C++.

I have to go through the png file and read the RGB data of a pixel: then I have 3 decimal values. From binary representation of the decimal values, I need the least smallest local value. The 11 pixels shows on 33 bits the length of the mp3. Then i decode all of the binary data from the pixels, and put in a vector;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define PNG_DEBUG 3
#include <png.h>

void abort_(const char * s, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, s);
        vfprintf(stderr, s, args);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        va_end(args);
        abort();
}

void itob(short n, std::vector<int> &bin)
{
    int d = n;

    if (n > 1)
    {
        d = n % 2;
        itob(n / 2, bin);
    }
    bin.push_back(d);
}

void btoi(unsigned int& n, std::vector<int> bin)
{
    n = 0;
    int k = 32;
    for(int i = 0; i < bin.size() ; i++){
        if(bin[i] == 1){
            long int num = pow(2,k);
            n += num;
        }
        k--;
    }
}

int x, y;

int width, height;
png_byte color_type;
png_byte bit_depth;

png_structp png_ptr;
png_infop info_ptr;
int number_of_passes;
png_bytep * row_pointers;

void read_png_file()
{
        unsigned char header[8];    // 8 is the maximum size that can be checked

        /* open file and test for it being a png */
        FILE *fp = fopen("image.png", "rb");
        if (!fp)
                abort_("[read_png_file] File %s could not be opened for reading", "image.png");
        fread(header, 1, 8, fp);
        if (png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 8))
                abort_("[read_png_file] File %s is not recognized as a PNG file", "image.png");


        /* initialize stuff */
        png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (!png_ptr)
                abort_("[read_png_file] png_create_read_struct failed");

        info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
        if (!info_ptr)
                abort_("[read_png_file] png_create_info_struct failed");

        png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
        png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

        png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

        width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        color_type = png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr);
        bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png_ptr, info_ptr);

        number_of_passes = png_set_interlace_handling(png_ptr);
        png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

        row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
        for (y=0; y<height; y++)
                row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*) malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr,info_ptr));

        png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

        fclose(fp);
}


void process_file(void)
{
        if (png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr) == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA)
                abort_("[process_file] input file is PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB but must be PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB "
                       "(lacks the alpha channel)");

        if (png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr) != PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB)
                abort_("[process_file] color_type of input file must be PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB (%d) (is %d)",
                       PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA, png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr));

        printf("width: %d\nheight: %d\n", width, height);

        int mHeader = 33; unsigned int mSize = 0;
        std::vector<int> mSizeByBites;
        for (y=0; y<height; y++) {
            png_byte* row = row_pointers[y];
            for (x=0; x<width; x++) {
                    png_byte* ptr = &(row[x*3]);
                    if(mHeader == 0){ break; }
                    mHeader-=3;

                    std::vector<int> b;

                    itob(ptr[0], b);
                    mSizeByBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                    b.clear();

                    itob(ptr[1], b);
                    mSizeByBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                    b.clear();

                    itob(ptr[2], b);
                    mSizeByBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                    b.clear();
                }
            if(mHeader == 0){ break; }
        }


        for(int i =0; i<mSizeByBites.size(); i++){
            printf("%d", mSizeByBites[i]);
        }
        btoi(mSize, mSizeByBites);
        printf(" = %i\n", mSize);

        std::vector<int> mDataBaBites;

        for (y=0; y<height; y++) {
            png_byte* row = row_pointers[y];
            for (x=0; x<width; x++) {
                if(mSize <= 0){ break; }

                png_byte* ptr = &(row[x*3]);
                std::vector<int> b;

                itob(ptr[0], b);
                mDataBaBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                b.clear();
                mSize--;
                if(mSize <= 0){ break; }
                itob(ptr[1], b);
                mDataBaBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                b.clear();
                mSize--;
                if(mSize <= 0){ break; }
                itob(ptr[2], b);
                mDataBaBites.push_back(b[b.size()-1]);
                b.clear();
                mSize--;
                if(mSize <= 0){ break; }
                printf("%i\n", mSize);
            }
            if(mSize<=0){ break; }
        }

        std::ofstream output("result.mp3", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        printf("[D] Writing to file start:    %li\n", mDataBaBites.size());
        output.write( (char*)(&mDataBaBites[0]), mDataBaBites.size() );
        output.close();

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        read_png_file();
        process_file();

        return 0;
}
```

Now I have no clue, how to write it in a file, wich i can play as an mp3. I tried to convert the bits to hexa.

What is the correct format of an mp3 file? How can I write the bits in the correct format?

Comment: If the mp3 file is really just the bits of the png, you should be able to just save the data. Just make sure that you're using binary mode.

Comment: What do you mean on 'binary mode'?

Comment: he means, that you have to create the ofstream with the std::ios::binary flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <fstream> //For std::min

std::ofstream mp3File( "restored.mp3", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
//Assuming rgbData is a char* with the mp3 data,
//and rgbDataSize is its size in bytes
mp3File.write( rgbData, rgbDataSize );
mp3File.close();
```

**Update**: When we (programmers) say "binary representation" we almost always mean bytes, not bits. From your description of the decoding process, I gather you should compare the 3 RGB components for each pixel and keep the minimum as the decoded byte. To do that:

```
#include <algorithm>

    //...

    std::vector<char> mDataBaBites;

    for (y=0; y<height; y++) {
        png_byte* row = row_pointers[y];
        for (x=0; x<width; x++) {
            png_byte red = row[x*3];
            png_byte green = row[x*3 + 1];
            png_byte blue = row[x*3 + 2];               
            png_byte minByte = std::min( std::min(red,green), blue );
            mDataBaBites.push_back( minByte );
            mSize -= 3;
        }
        if(mSize<=0){ break; }
    }

    std::ofstream output("result.mp3", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    printf("[D] Writing to file start:    %li\n", mDataBaBites.size());
    output.write( (char*)(&mDataBaBites[0]), mDataBaBites.size() );
    output.close();
```

**Update 2**:

```
    std::ofstream output("result.mp3", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    printf("[D] Writing to file start:    %li\n", mDataBaBites.size());
    for( int i=0; i<mDataBaBites.size(); i+=8 ){
       char decodedByte = 0;
       for( int j=0; j<8; j++ )
          decodedByte |= (mDataBaBites[i+j] << j);
       output.write( (char*)(&mDataBaBites[0]), 1 );
    }
    output.close();
```

If this doesn't work either, you might want to clarify the decoding process definition (which is its source? is there some formal definition?)

Comment: I have a vector<int> which stores the bits: 1010101000111...
The data is in the bits. If I do as you said, I just get a file full of these 0s and 1s. :\

Comment: If v[0]=1, that is, the number 1, this won't work. The binary representation of that number will be written (which will consist of 32 or 64 bits according to the targetted platform), not a 1. You need to read the mp3 data as a `vector<char>` or `char*` (pure binary data). Posting your code would be helpful.

Comment: With the updated description I can now write a good binary file. But still not a valid mp3.

Comment: That's not good either. When I look at a R,B or G value, I have to convert it to binary. For example: r=10 -> 1010. Then I have to choose the smallest local value: 101[0]. These numbers from each pixels each RGB values, concatenated, represents an mp3 file data. Thats why I use vector<int>.

Comment: If it's really that way, how about grabbing the ints by groups of 8 and creating a byte from that? That's what Update 2 does.